# What exactly falls under the term "moment" of a distribution?

Tags: terminology, moments, information-theory

Whenever people talk about the set of moments of a random variable X, they usually are referring to $\{E(X^n)|n\in \mathbb N \}$, where $E(X_n)$ is called the **"$n$'th moment"**.

Also, $\{E[(X-E(X)]^n)|n\in \mathbb N \}$ is the set of "$n$'th central moments".

**However, we can define a more general class,** namely the set of functionals from probability distributions $P=\{F(\cdot)|F:\mathbb R\to [0,1],F \text { increasing}\}$ to real numbers:

$$M=\{J|J:P\to \mathbb R \}$$

For example, the Shannon information: $E[\ln(p(X))]\in M$.

**Do we also refer to elements in this more general class $M$ as "moments" of the distribution of $X$? If not, what word do we use for it?** More specifically, is there a named class of functionals of which both the mean, variance, etc, and the Shannon entropy are members?

Comment: What kind of "functionals" are you referring to?  That is, what properties do you suppose they have?  Regardless, nobody understands "moment" in such a sense.  In the most general sense, the word refers to expectations of powers of $|X|$.

Answer (score 2):

In [statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics) and [probability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory), a [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) is the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of a power of the distance between a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) and a point from the space where this variable takes values. For a random variable $ \xi $ that takes values in a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), we can define a the moment of order $n$ about the point $c$, where $n$ is a non-negative integer writing:

$$ m_n = E({ d(\xi,c)^n } ) \quad n \in N $$

If $ \alpha $ is a real number, we can speak of a moment of order $\alpha$ writing:

$$ m_{\alpha} = E( d(\xi,c)^{\alpha} ) $$

For a real valued random variable $\xi$ and a non-negative integer $n$ we can define the moment of order $n$ about the point $c$ writing:

$$ m_n = E((\xi - c)^n) $$